# Django whitespace from textarea into a list of dictionary

Tags: django

I hope someone here can help me out of this.

I have a `request.POST` from textarea, for example:

```
<QueryDict: {'Animal':['Fish Dog Cat Bird']}>
```

I want to convert to something like this:

```
{'Animal': ['Fish', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird']}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    'Animal': request.POST.get('Animal').split(' ')
}
```